# How to create a correct table?

Tags: html, html-table

I have a problem with making a table in HTML.
The table should look like in this image:

[image]

And the second image is how I made:

[image]

This is my code:

```html
<table width="730" border="1px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
  <tr align="center">
    <td rowspan="3">A</td>
    <td rowspan="2">B</td>
    <td rowspan="3">D</td>
    <td>E</td>
    <td>F</td>
    <td>G</td>
  </tr>
  <tr align="center">
    <td rowspan="2" colspan="3">H</td>
  </tr>
  <tr align="center">
    <td>C</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

How to create a table like in the first image?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: How to create a table like in the first image?

Comment: Simply set `height: 50px;` to your "B" cell

Comment: What sort of data do you have that is reasonably represented by that table structure?!

Comment: Your table _does_ match your mockup image except for cell size (which normally depends on content). It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: Your Problem is not clear. Please give some more details about your problem.

Comment: furthermore, this will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Ohhh, cmon guys! The question is HOW TO CREATE A  HTML TABLE LIKE IN THE FIRST IMAGE?!?

Comment: No no no, we have no ideia what're talking about you need to read the how-to-ask and reexplain with more details, otherwise this question won't help the community to create a repository of good questions and answers, that's why you must be sUre to give us a MiNimal rEproducible example asap or we will downvote your question as it needs to be more clear and needs debugging informmmmmation and you haven't even sHowed your own attempt so we will not help you or guide you b3cause this is a hOmEwOrK question and we don't answer these kinda of questions here, go back to the basics,

Answer (score 0):

```css
.grey{ background: rgba(128,128,128,0.7); }
```

```html
<table width="730" border="1px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
      <tr align="center">
        <td rowspan="3">A</td>
        <td rowspan="2" height="60px">B</td>
        <td rowspan="3">D</td>
        <td class="grey">E</td>
        <td class="grey">F</td>
        <td class="grey">G</td>
      </tr>
      <tr align="center">
        <td rowspan="2" colspan="3">H</td>
      </tr>
      <tr align="center">
        <td>C</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case the only things you can do are

1.) Add more content to the cells. If the amount of contents corresponds to the cell heights, they will adjust automatically.

or

2.) If you intend to have as little contents as in your example code, add a `height` setting to one of the cells that are supposed to span two rows - see snippet below.

```html
<table width="730" border="1px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
  <tr align="center">
    <td rowspan="3">A</td>
    <td rowspan="2" style="height:3em;">B</td>
    <td rowspan="3">D</td>
    <td>E</td>
    <td>F</td>
    <td>G</td>
  </tr>
  <tr align="center">
    <td rowspan="2" colspan="3">H</td>
  </tr>
  <tr align="center">
    <td>C</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```